# Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, razorpdf

I know this may be a duplicate, because I found this problems on many forms, but none of the answers worked for me.
I tried to generate a pdf in asp.net mvc 5 using RazorPDF, and at execution time I got this error:
Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'

I added the path to itextsharp.dll in environmental variables, I use 'any CPU' option in build properties, but nothing helps.
If any of you managed to solve this, please help me/
Thank you.

Comment: Verify you have added a reference to the specified version.

Comment: It looks like your using an assembly build for Silverlight 5. Is there no assembly specific to your framework version?

Comment: the  reference is added, the problem is that a function from itextsharp is throwing an exeption.

Comment: Silvermind, I am a beginner with asp.net and I donțt really undestood your question